# What does ">> 3" mean? Is it a redirection of some kind?

Tags: c, bit-shift

I am attempting to figure out what

```
 >> 3
```

does in the code shown below. Is >> a redirect and if so, then what is 3? 
Can someone help?

```
#define BYTESIZE(bitsize)       ((bitsize + 7) >> 3)
```

Comment: As an aside, the other meaning of `>>` is called the "extraction operator," not "redirect."  Perhaps you were thinking of shell syntax, where `>` redirects output to a file.

Comment: @Lotharyx: In shell syntax, `>>` appends to a file (which has nothing to do with the C operator that happens to look similar).

Comment: You're right.  `>` by itself overwrites the file.  I was just trying to correct the OP's jargon. :-)

Comment: BTW, the macro definition should parenthesize its arguments to avoid operator precedence problems: `#define BYTESIZE(bitsize) (((bitsize) + 7) >> 3)`

Comment: I added the bit-shift tag. @user2936723 I realize you did not know this is what it is but it is the relevant category.

Comment: I've updated your title to make it clearer to future readers.

Comment: I wish the people who downvoted the question at least left a comment. I don't see any negative or critical comments, the question is written well enough.

Comment: I'd make this a new answer but I don't want the downvotes.. :-)  `<3` means she loves you.  `>3` means she doesn't.  `>>3` means she wants you to die in a fire.

Comment: @Dogbert - Probably people who thought the guy should have figured it out on his own by learning more about the language.  Personally I think it's an okay question because `>>` does have multiple meanings.

Comment: @Lotharyx </3 means it will never happen.

Comment: If you don't have a good reference book that contains a list of C operators, find something online and bookmark it.  You should not have to ask questions like this.

Comment: @HotLicks It's true this kind of thing is obviously found in a table but since bit shift is so prominently overloaded in C++ it's a weird case. I took entry CS classes and they didn't really tell us it was actually a bit shift. I thought I knew what it was too for a little while so I understand why the question pops up on here so frequently.

Comment: @Radiodef - That's why you should have the reference.  (And use it.)

Comment: @HotLicks I agree, I'm just saying the bit shift is a special case since it now has a habit of birthing a weird kind of ignorance. Especially in C++ where it could very well be basically [the first operator a new programmer ever uses](http://www.cplusplus.com/doc/tutorial/program_structure/). (Note that they even spuriously call it "the insertion operator".)

Comment: @Radiodef - Certainly C++ did screw the pooch by needlessly overloading a number of operators in entirely non-intuitive ways.

Comment: @Radiodef - `<<` is indeed called the insertion operator.  And shift left.

Comment: Many thanks for all your answers, responses and humor!

Comment: @user2936723 If you found the answer helpful, please mark it as the accepted answer by clicking the hollow checkmark to the left.  Marking accepted answers rewards the answerer with reputation points.  Thanks! :-)

Answer (score 5):

`>>` is the right shift operator.  Right-shift takes a binary value and shifts it right by the right-hand operand.  For example:

```
0100 >> 1 == 0010
00010000 >> 4 == 00000001
```

In decimal terms, this is the same as dividing by powers of two.  `>> 1` divides by two, `>> 2` divides by four, `>> 3` divides by 8, etc.

Comment: The `+ 7` part is actually interesting too: effectively it rounds up to the nearest multiple of 8. So for example `BYTESIZE(14)` returns 2.

Comment: It's a pretty clever macro, but the OP was only asking about `>>`. (-:

Comment: Yep! Just an addendum.

Comment: Nothing especially "clever" about the `+7` thing -- it's an old, very well-established idiom.

Comment: @HotLicks I know that, I'm just being polite to Radiodef, as I thought it was worth mentioning.

Comment: @Dogbert Now how to do  `((x + 7) >> 3)` and guard against overflow due to `+ 7`?  Maybe `(x >> 3) + (((x&7) + 7) >> 3)`?  (But then that uses `x` twice - potential macro issue.)

Comment: @chux Simple. Avoid side effects in a macro, avoid macros even more if the sequence point is in doubt, wrap the entire macro in a `{do..while(0)}` to keep LINT and static code analysis tools from preventing the code from being allowed to build or potentially screwing up the program flow if the macro is called in nested code blocks, and learn how to use inline functions.

Comment: Many thanks for all your answers, responses and humor!